# What is the difference between these two C++ statements to concatenate a string?

Tags: c++, string, concatenation, c-strings, string-literals

I'm new to C++ and I was wondering what the difference is between these two lines:

```
cout << "John " << "Doe" << endl;
cout << "John " + "Doe" << endl;
```

The first one works but the second one doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: The first one prints `John Doe` … The second, does not. You're actually adding two arrays together, which won't compile. [Try it and see](https://godbolt.org/z/gC4yJU)

Comment: You should add `cout << "John "s + "Doe"s << endl;` to your question. That's how string literals are concatenated. https://wandbox.org/permlink/WaW4Kx8LHXh5KdX6

Comment: Neither concatenates strings.  The first prints two distinct strings with nothing output between them.   The second does not compile.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2):

The first line

```
cout << "John " << "Doe" << endl;
```

doesn't concatenate strings. It prints "John " and then it prints "Doe". But there never existed a string "John Doe".

The second line

```
cout << "John " + "Doe" << endl;
```

is syntactically wrong. There is no `operator+` overloaded for char arrays.

To concatenate string literals you can use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::literals::string_literals::operator""s;

int main() {
    std::cout << "John "s + "Doe"s << std::endl;
    // or
    auto name = "John "s + "Doe"s;
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

since C++14. [`operator""s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) creates a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) with [`operator+`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B).

Answer (score 2):

The second expression is evaluated as

```
cout << ("John " + "Doe") << endl;
```

due to the language grammar (often thought of as *operator precedence*).

But `"John "` is a `const char[6]` type and `"Doe"` is `const char[4]` type. Due to the `+`, both *decay* to a `const char*` pointer. And pointers cannot be added, so the compiler issues a diagnostic.

---

In the first case, the overload `<<` on `std::ostream` for a `const char*` is used twice, with the results you expect.

Answer (score 1):

First one inserts "John " into the standard output, and then it inserts "Doe". End result is that you see both strings in a sequence.

The second attempts to use the addition operator with arrays as operands. This is ill-formed because such operator does not exist in C++.

Answer (score 1):

For starters there is no concatenation of strings.

In the first statement

```
cout << "John " << "Doe" << endl;
```

there are outputted sequentially two strings.

In the second statement

```
cout << "John " + "Doe" << endl;
```

there is an attempt to perform the binary operation `+` with two pointers of the type `const char *` to which the used string literals having array types are implicitly converted. However the operator `+` is not defined for pointers.

You may use the operator `-` for pointers like

```
std::cout << "John " - "Doe" << std::endl;
```

This statement syntactically correct but semantically has undefined behavior because the pointers do not point to elements of the same array.

Built-in array types do not have the binary operator +.

This operator is overloaded for the user-defined class template `std::basic_string`.

You could write for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::string( "John " ) + "Doe" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or you could use a user-defined string literal like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    std::cout << "John "s + "Doe" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or in the C++ 17 Standard there is defined new class template `std::string_view` that you also could use to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate two literal strings, just write one after the other with no intervening characters other than whitespace:

```
const char *lit = "John " "Doe";
std::cout << lit << '\n';
```

or

```
std::cout << "John "

    "Doe";
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second one does not work is that you can't concatenate two string literals with `+` operator. On the other hand, the first approach utilizes [chaining of insertion operators](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Chaining) to print multiple expressions

Answer (score 0):

The first method is the correct method to concatenate two strings in C++. Whereas the second method, is by default the method to concatenate two strings in Python.

You can't use the second as it is not supported as it indicates addition of two strings and not concatenation (as seen by c++ compiler).

Answer (score -1):

String literals like `"foo"` cannot be added (i.e. `operator+`) together for concatenation like in many other languages. This is reasonable in a low-level language like C++ because (in the general case) that would mean an allocation would have to take place.

However, if you are fine with that, then you can use `std::string` objects which do have those facilities for you. The following works:

```
cout << string("John ") + string("Doe") << endl;
```

Comment: `"John " "Doe"` concatenates the two string literals. It is equivalent to `"John Doe"`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I wrote "*added*", which means performing addition (`operator+`). Writing `"John " "Doe"` is not an addition. I edited the answer to be (even) more explicit.